# What is the behaviour of the container if the servlet class is made final

Tags: java, servlets

I want the behavior of the servlet container ,when the custom servlet is made `final`

```
final class AtomikosServlet extends HttpServlet
{

..
..
..
}
```

Comment: @jigar:i  tried , but didnt see any changes.

Comment: What's the difference you expected?

Comment: @AlexR: I didnt expect any difference, but suddenly got confused when it was asked to me in an interview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behavior from the point of the container is unchanged.

Making the servlet final means it cannot be subclassed.